# vue js spa and laravel sanctum: cannot set crsf-cookie

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum

### CONTEXT AND GOAL

I have my laravel backend running on backend.domain

I have a vuejs spa trying to logging in from 'external.app.domain'

I need that vuejs spa can login, obatain A NEW token for the user, to, then, use for subsequent calls.

### WHAT I DID

I am following this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#csrf-protection

The call to sanctum/csrf-cookie works, but I got this from chrome

[image]

Axios in vue app is using

```
withCredentials: true,
```

Backend cors.php file has

```
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Backend sanctum.php file has `external.app.domain` in the `stateful` array

### THE MAIN PROBLEM

The problem is that calling /login to obtain a token I got this

```
CSRF token mismatch.
```

### Simple question

What else must I do !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I had to *remove* the middleware of sanctum in api.
I previously enabled because I was trying other way to use Sanctum itself.